# Data being deleted in listview upon scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-studio-3.0

I know this question has been asked before, but mine is a bit different. And after reading their answer it didn't help, I am a bit new to Android Studio, so any help would be appreciated.....As the title suggests, I am finding that when I scroll down in my ListView, and then scroll back up, the values are being deleted... Essentially what I am asking is what do I do in my getView of my custom adapter class to get information like when clicking a table another word is inserted in the table, from getting that word getting deleted..to illustrate the problem i have attached a gif....
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TIuVtbXn30W5KIDqCnC_f5mKQ5oIuVJ1

Comment: It is impossible to help you without you posting the code.

Comment: what code, i want to avoid post 500 + lines of getView.. but if need be ill cult some of the senstivie stuff out

Comment: How on earth could it be 500 lines?

Comment: A lot of volley's (each is like 50 lines) , with conditional changes to the adapter....

Comment: Still a totally ridiculous number of lines in one method.

Comment: Also, the fact you are making Volley calls inside getView sounds suspect.

Comment: Could we start a chat group I have some indivual questions that are very specfici?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173303/discussion-between-jewstin-and-theblitz).